# Check if timestamp is between limits

Tags: python, datetime

I m looking for a solution to  make inside a reading log file processus a compare to check the time range within of the current line

currently I have :

variables : datetime_ed & datetime_sd as enddate & startdate with each fd_fmt as '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M'

the current existing code block looks like

```
with open(f, "r") as fi:#, open(output_file, "w") as fo:
     for line in fi:
     #for pattern in REGEXES:
          if REGEXES[0].search(line):  # search by ID instead of the wordslist at first
               match = REGEXES[1].search(line)
               if match:
                    line_id = match.group(1)
                    # doing stuff here
```

so I would do something like

```
with open(f, "r") as fi:#, open(output_file, "w") as fo:
     for line in fi:
     #for pattern in REGEXES:
          if REGEXES[0].search(line):  # search by ID instead of the wordslist at first
               match = REGEXES[1].search(line)
               #ONLY IF LINE CONTAIN DATE BETWEEN datetime_ed & datetime_sd
                    if match:
                        line_id = match.group(1)
                        # doing stuff here
```

how to do that ?
didn't found a function to do so in datetime documents

as temporary solution I made that :

```
                with open(f, "r") as fi:#, open(output_file, "w") as fo:
                        for line in fi:
                                
                                try:
                                        ts = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[:16], fd_fmt) # try/except to avoid issues with non-dated lines
                                except ValueError:
                                        pass
                                #print("ts ",ts)
                                if datetime_sd < ts < datetime_ed :
                                        #for pattern in REGEXES:
                                        if REGEXES[0].search(line):  # search by ID instead of the wordslist at first
                                                match = REGEXES[1].search(line)
                                                if match:
#etc...
```

Is this good / correct ?

Comment: You may be interested in the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which is focused on answering this sort of questions. StackOverflow is meant to find solutions to problem.